# Using a black box MCMC algorithm as a proposal distribution

Tags: sampling, markov-chain-montecarlo

Let's say I have some MCMC algorithm implemented as a function, `black_box(x)`, which generates samples from $P(x)$ when run in a chain. I would now like to sample from $P(x)G(x)$. Is it possible to use `black_box(x)` as proposal distribution and then use Independent Metropolis, i.e.:

1) Let `x' = black_box(x)`.

2) Accept with probability `min(1, G(x') / G(x))`

3) Loop to 1)

How can I prove that this works?

**First attempt**

Let `B(x -> x')` be the probability that `black_box(x)` returns `x'`.
Assuming that `black_box(x)` implements a Metropolis-Hastings algorithm, we know that it fulfills detailed balance, i.e.

$\frac{B(x \rightarrow x')}{B(x' \rightarrow x)} = \frac{P(x')}{P(x)}$

If we choose our acceptance probability as

$A(x \rightarrow x') = \min(1, \frac{G(x')}{G(x)})$

the overall transition probability fulfills detailed balance since

$\frac{B(x \rightarrow x')A(x \rightarrow x')}{B(x' \rightarrow x)A(x' \rightarrow x)} = \frac{P(x')\min(1, G(x') / G(x))}{P(x)\min(1, G(x) / G(x'))} = \frac{P(x')G(x')}{P(x)G(x)}$ (since either $\frac{G(x)}{G(x')} \gt 1$ or $\frac{G(x)}{G(x')} \le 1$).

**Problem**

However, the above doesn't work in the general case, since there are MCMC algorithms that does not guarantee detailed balance. For example, [each sweep of the deterministic sweep Gibbs sampler does not satisfy detailed balance](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/118442/does-the-gibbs-sampling-algorithm-guarantee-detailed-balance). Is there a way to fix the above solution to make it work, or is it impossible? What requirements does `black_box(x)` have to fulfill in order to allow it to be used as a proposal distribution?

Comment: I'd like to know why this question was voted down. It looks interesting and shows thought.

Answer (score 3):

It a nearly equivalent way to do this is via importance sampling. In other words,

1) Draw $M$ samples from $P(X)$. Let's call these samples $X'$.

2) Get importance weights by computing $w = G(X')$

3) Calculate whatever statistic you want (i.e. mean, sd, etc) by the weights incorporation $w' = \frac{w}{\sum w}$

4) If you want to get an unweighted sample from P(X)G(X), draw from $X'$ with probability $w'$

Comment: Unfortunately this requires $M \rightarrow \infty$, and this is taking place within a larger MCMC algorithm, so I can't let $M$ be too large.